# some problems when installing torchaudio on mac

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

I use following command to install `torchaudio`:`"conda install -c derickl torchaudio"`. But when I try to import `torchaudio` the following error message pops up:

[image: The error message]

Can someone take a look or propose some other ways to install `torchaudio`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This sequence seems to work as of August/2019

```
# update conda
conda update -n base -c defaults conda  --yes
```

```
# create environment 
conda create -n torchaudio -c pytorch pytorch>=1.2.0
```

```
source activate torchaudio
```

```
pip install torchaudio
```

```
python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torchaudio
>>> torchaudio.initialize_sox()
0`
```